# dotnet restore fails for private nuget packages

Tags: .net-core, nuget, ubuntu-16.04

I developed a web api (.net core) in windows and hosting it in ubuntu server. My application needs packages from private nuget repository.
I have set the package source as `nuget config -Set RepoName=http://sample-nuget-repo.net/api/odata`.
I have verified with nuget resources.
When I run dotnet restore, it gives me failure messages.
Please help me if i am missing anything.

what is the location of nuget.config file in ubuntu (as in windows it is appdata/nuget/nuget.config)

Comment: dotnet restore app.sln --source http://sample-nuget-repo.net/api/odata solved my problem

Comment: can we configure it globally?

Answer (score 16):

You can define custom package sources in a NuGet.Config file in the root directory of your source control repository containing your source code. Then you do not need to configure it on every machine.

NuGet.Config:

```
<configuration>
    <packageSources>
        <add key="NuGet.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
        <add key="sample-nuget-repo" value="http://sample-nuget-repo.net/api/odata" />
    </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

When you run a `nuget restore solution.sln` or `dotnet restore solution.sln` the solution's directory will be checked first for a NuGet.Config file, then the directory above, all the way back to the root directory. Finally the NuGet.Config under the user's profile will be checked.

Comment: Thanks Matt. Yes the nuget package sources are stored in nuget.config in windows. Is the nuget.config created on linux as well. If yes what is the location of this file

Comment: You can use a NuGet.Config file on any platform (Linux, Mac and Windows). You just need to create it with your source code so it is standalone and does not require extra setup on the build server). If you want to configure it individually on the build server you would need to add this information in the ~/.config/NuGet/NuGet.config file or use `nuget` itself to add this package source in a build script.